# How to call another action from inside a redux toolkit action

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

```js
const scoreSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'score',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addScore: ({ score }, action) => {
      score += action.payload;
    },
    reset: (state) => {
      state.score = 0;
      state.grid = initialState.grid;
      generateCard(2); // How do we do this?
    },
    generateCard: (state, action: PayloadAction<number>) => {

    },
  },
});
```

I created a `scoreSlice` `slice` and created 3 actions: `addScore` `reset` `generateCard`.

When I execute the `reset` action, I want the `generateCard` action to also work. How can I do this?

Comment: Can't you dispatch these two actions in the same place?

Comment: @LinDu I can do that, but I think it's cleaner to do it inside the store. Is it common practice to ask for two actions in a component?

Comment: @LinDu
```js
  const handleReset = () => {
    dispatch(reset());
    dispatch(generateCard(2));
  };
```

Are you talking about something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a common practice to dispatch multiple actions.

- Option 1. Dispatch actions directly to the event handler.

```js
const handler = () => {
  dispatch(reset());
  dispatch(generateCard(2))
}
```

- Option 2. Create a thunk to compose related actions (need [`redux-thunk`](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) middleware)

```js
const resetAndGenerateCard = (cardNumber) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(reset());
    dispatch(generateCard(cardNumber))
  }
};

const handler = () => dispatch(resetAndGenerateCard(cardNumber))
```

- Option 3. Create a new special action combine these two action types, and handle it in a special reducer. (The "special" is not really special, it just needs you to think of an action type to represent the meaning of this action. The `action1AndAction2` format maybe not good action type)

```js
const resetAndGenerateCard = (payload) => ({ type: 'RESET_AND_GENERATE_CARD', payload });
// ...
{ 
  resetAndGenerateCardReducer: (state, action) => {
    // reset
    state.score = 0;
    state.grid = initialState.grid;
    // generate card 
    state.cards = [...state.cards, action.payload];
  }
}
// ...

const handler = () => dispatch(resetAndGenerateCard(2))
```

But sometimes there are trade-offs. Take a look at [Should I dispatch multiple actions in a row from one action creator?](https://redux.js.org/faq/actions#should-i-dispatch-multiple-actions-in-a-row-from-one-action-creator)